# Checkbox Mandatory (to Check by User) in Visual Studio Form

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I'm new in Visual Studio and want to make a Check Box Mandatory (to Check by User) in a Form before Closing it or go for any other Event. How can I do this?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Could you please share your attempted code ?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Could you please specify your question a bit more. What do you mean by "Mandatory Check Box"? There is no such a functionality as far as I know. Your question could also be understood as "How to cancel application/form close from user until he check a checkbox on form?" Was it this what you meant by the question?

Comment: You means winforms, WPF or what ?

Comment: 1st I wan to start with WinForms.... Thanks.

Comment: add a condition to checkbox.checked

Comment: @CommonMan, Thanks for your tips. It helps.

Comment: @SajjadAli welcome, i wrote below the pseudo code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if(checkbox.Checked)
{
     //add your conditions
}

else
{
      //Add conditions to stay on the same win form
}
```